# Wso2 Cluster Deployment: some nodes didn't apply a password policy

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

I've deployed wso2 store, carbon and publisher on multiple nodes/boxes.

So each nodes has its specific role like store node, carbon node or publisher node.

The problem is store node didn't pick up the password policy when I tried to change a user password through the carbon admin dashboard. However, the other nodes were able to pick up the password policy.

All the nodes have same configuration under `repository/conf/security/identity-mgt.properties` and all of them have same identity.mgt jar file with the same f

Is there anything I need to check or change to configure the password policy setting?

Comment: Can you add line `log4j.logger.org.wso2.carbon.identity.mgt=DEBUG` to `<STORE_HOME>/repository/conf/log4j.properties file, restart the store and retry the same and update the question with the additional logs you see?

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't get an issue on the store node, if have same configs and it has identity management feature installed similar to other nodes. I agree (Hence my comment to get more details).

But as I can see, what you doing here is architecturally incorrect.

What you trying to do here is have a distributed setup of API manager. In that scenario, Store node only should be serving store related operations. So changing the password from the carbon console on the store node is not valid. Instead, it should have done on the carbon node.

There should be shared databases, user-stores connected to each these servers, so change in the one (the dedicated node to dedicated operations) should reflect on other nodes as needed.

Refer [1] for the step-by-step instruction on setting up API manager distributed setup for API Manager 1.10.0. It seems you are using a earlier version, and you will be able to browse and find the guide for your exact version.

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER44x/Clustering+API+Manager+1.10.0

HTH, DarRay